# How to make a listview/recycleview like ios style on android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I created a listview which display all the application installed on my phone,
But I want to make it more similar to the listview of ios

My xml file

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Applications"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="none"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[The listview I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Rj4.png)

How to move the icon image to the left side of the center of listview divider
(The x mark)

[Sketch of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COEMc.png)

Comment: The layout in each row of the ListView will depend on what view you inflate in your adapter. You should include that view XML in your question too, and more clearly indicate (maybe with a sketch?) what you want the rows to actually look like.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a left margin(or padding) attribute in the list cell.
Please remove it.

or
You can make a cell like this.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout> 
//icon and text content 
</LinearLayout> 
<TextView margin-left="32dp" BackgroundColor="#888"> 
//this will be the divider that has left margin
</TextView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond,but what i mean is I want to move the icon image in the center of divider

Comment: #1
For now the divider is just to split cells. and there is an icon is one cell.

So that I think you need to move the divider line to the center of a cell.
----------------
#2
You have to make the diver by yourself.
<RelativeLayout ....>
    <LinearLayout ...>
        // icon and text content
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView  .....   padding-left="32dp" backgroundColor="#888">
        // this will be the divider
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecyclerView for displaying a list of views. Recycler uses adapter for displaying multiple items.
This code will help you build the same item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivICon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivICon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivICon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivICon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivICon" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Use this tutorial for [Recycler View](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview/)